# how to get ip address as a string

Tags: c, string, libpcap

I'm developing a network sniffer based on `libpcap` in C programming language.

Already I have one function which can print the IP address as follows:

```c
void print_ipaddress(ipaddress *i) {
    for (unsigned int n = 0; n < i->p_int; n++) {
        printf("%d", i->p_data[n]);
        if (n < i->p_int - 1) printf(".");
    }
    printf("\n"); 
}
```

the `ipaddress` structure is created by my program and the data is copied from `libpcap`. (In fact, you don't need to care about the details about this function). The above function can print the ip address correctly.

Next step, I want to store the ip address as a string. So I write the following function:

```c
char* get_ipaddress(ipaddress *i) {
    char *ip = malloc(sizeof(char)*20);
    for(unsigned int n = 0; n < i->p_int; n++) {
        char s[3];
        sprintf(s, "%d", i->p_data[n]);
        strcat(ip, s);
        if (n < i->p_int - 1) {
            strcat(ip, ".");
        }
    }
    return ip;
}
```

But the string contains some mess code as follows:

```c
I'V172.17.98.31
```

I was a little bit confused how to handle each byte as a string and append them together.

Comment: Off-topic: `sizeof(char)` by definition is 1, so you actually just add clutter. If you swap to `wchar_t` some day for some reason you'd need to adjust. Rather prefer `char* ip = malloc(20*sizeof(*ip))`. That's safer.

Comment: You can call the function [`inet_ntoa`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/inet_ntoa) to convert an IP address to a string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ip` is not initialized.

```
char *ip = malloc(20);
ip[0] = 0;
```

You should check the result of `malloc` to avoid dereferencing the NULL pointer

Comment: Or you can use `char *ip = calloc(20, sizeof(char));`

Answer (score 1):

You can write to the `ip` array directly:

```
for(unsigned int n = 0; n < i->p_int; ++n)
{
    ip += sprintf(ip, "%d.", i->p_data[i]);
}
*--ip = 0; // remove the trailing dot
```

Note that any function out of the `printf` returns the number of bytes it has written.

Of course you'd backup original value of `ip` to be able to return it...

Apart from you need to check the return value of `malloc` as `0___________` mentioned already in his answer.

Note, too, that the separator character in IPv6 case typically rather is a colon (`:`) than a period (`.`), so you might consider that for `n > 4`.

If you are guaranteed to have IPv4 only you could do instead:

```
if(i->p_int == 4) // otherwise you consider i invalid anyway...
{
    printf("%d.%d.%d.%d", i->p_data[0], i->p_data[1], i->p_data[2], i->p_data[3]);
}
```